# How to change border color of text field?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, border

I am trying to change the border color of an `UITextField`, I cant find any option to change it in Main(base) and the code I am using in viewController is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textsa: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textsa.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(red: 23, green: 23, blue: 23, alpha: 12.3)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `borderColor` and `borderWidth` of the textfield 's layer:

```
textsa?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
textsa?.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```